# hasChildNodes always return undefined

Tags: javascript, tree, children

I work on a recursive function :

```
function Recursive(JSObject) {

    for(let JSChild of JSObject.children) {
        console.log(JSChild.name);
        console.log(JSChild.hasChildNodes);
        /*if(JSChild.hasChildNodes) {
            Recursive(JSChild);
        }*/
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the line :

> console.log(JSChild.hasChildNodes);

always return "undefined" whereas some nodes have one or more children.
Furthermore, [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_haschildnodes.asp) uses some brackets at the end of hasChildNodes but when I do it my browser (Chrome) return this error :

> JSChild.hasChildNodes is not a function

I don't understand why nothing is working.
I would be grateful if you can help me.

EDIT : (object in JSON format)

```
{
  "dir":"",
  "name":"myProject",
  "type":"folder",
  "children":[
    {
      "dir":"myProject",
      "name":"css",
      "type":"folder",
      "children":[
        {
          "dir":"myProject/css",
          "name":"main.css",
          "type":"file"
        },
        {
          "dir":"myProject/css",
          "name":"menu.css",
          "type":"file"
        },
        {
          "dir":"myProject/css",
          "name":"user.css",
          "type":"file"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dir":"myProject",
      "name":"fonts",
      "type":"folder"
    },
    {
      "dir":"myProject",
      "name":"images",
      "type":"folder",
      "children":[
        {
          "dir":"myProject/images",
          "name":"logo.png",
          "type":"file",
          "corrupted":true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dir":"myProject",
      "name":"index.html",
      "type":"file"
    },
    {
      "dir":"myProject",
      "name":"js",
      "type":"folder",
      "children":[
        {
          "dir":"myProject/js",
          "name":"controllers",
          "type":"folder",
          "children":[
            {
              "dir":"myProject/js/controllers",
              "name":"core",
              "type":"folder",
              "children":[
                {
                  "dir":"myProject/tempjs/controllerslates/core",
                  "name":"menu.js",
                  "type":"file"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "dir":"myProject/js/controllers",
              "name":"errors",
              "type":"folder",
              "children":[
                {
                  "dir":"myProject/js/controllers/errors",
                  "name":"error.js",
                  "type":"file"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "dir":"myProject/js/controllers",
              "name":"home",
              "type":"folder",
              "children":[
                {
                  "dir":"myProject/js/controllers/home",
                  "name":"homePage.js",
                  "type":"file"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "dir":"myProject/js/controllers",
              "name":"home",
              "type":"folder",
              "children":[
                {
                  "dir":"myProject/js/controllers/user",
                  "name":"list.js",
                  "type":"file"
                },
                {
                  "dir":"myProject/js/controllers/user",
                  "name":"login.js",
                  "type":"file"
                },
                {
                  "dir":"myProject/js/controllers/user",
                  "name":"profile.js",
                  "type":"file"
                },
                {
                  "dir":"myProject/js/controllers/user",
                  "name":"subscribe.js",
                  "type":"file"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "dir":"myProject/js",
          "name":"libs",
          "type":"folder",
          "children":[
            {
              "dir":"myProject/js/libs",
              "name":"handlebars.min.js",
              "type":"file"
            },
            {
              "dir":"myProject/js/libs",
              "name":"jquery.min.js",
              "type":"file"
            },
            {
              "dir":"myProject/js/libs",
              "name":"require.min.js",
              "type":"file",
              "corrupted":true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "dir":"myProject/js",
          "name":"main.js",
          "type":"file"
        },
        {
          "dir":"myProject/js",
          "name":"models",
          "type":"folder",
          "children":[
            {
              "dir":"myProject/js/models",
              "name":"menu.js",
              "type":"file"
            },
            {
              "dir":"myProject/js/models",
              "name":"user.js",
              "type":"file"
            },
            {
              "dir":"myProject/js/models",
              "name":"users.js",
              "type":"file"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "dir":"myProject",
      "name":"ressources",
      "type":"folder"
    },
    {
      "dir":"myProject",
      "name":"views",
      "type":"folder",
      "children":[
        {
          "dir":"myProject/templates",
          "name":"core",
          "type":"folder",
          "children":[
            {
              "dir":"myProject/templates/core",
              "name":"footer.html",
              "type":"file"
            },
            {
              "dir":"myProject/templates/core",
              "name":"header.html",
              "type":"file"
            },
            {
              "dir":"myProject/templates/core",
              "name":"menu.html",
              "type":"file"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "dir":"myProject/templates",
          "name":"errors",
          "type":"folder",
          "children":[
            {
              "dir":"myProject/templates/errors",
              "name":"error401.html",
              "type":"file"
            },
            {
              "dir":"myProject/templates/errors",
              "name":"error403.html",
              "type":"file"
            },
            {
              "dir":"myProject/templates/errors",
              "name":"error404.html",
              "type":"file",
              "corrupted":true
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "dir":"myProject/templates",
          "name":"home",
          "type":"folder",
          "children":[
            {
              "dir":"myProject/templates/home",
              "name":"homePage.html",
              "type":"file"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "dir":"myProject/templates",
          "name":"home",
          "type":"folder",
          "children":[
            {
              "dir":"myProject/templates/user",
              "name":"list.html",
              "type":"file"
            },
            {
              "dir":"myProject/templates/user",
              "name":"login.html",
              "type":"file"
            },
            {
              "dir":"myProject/templates/user",
              "name":"profile.html",
              "type":"file"
            },
            {
              "dir":"myProject/templates/user",
              "name":"subscribe.html",
              "type":"file"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Note: [`hasChildNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/hasChildNodes) is a method not a property, and needs to be invoked.

Comment: Can you share the `JSObject` that you are iterating over?

Comment: If I can give you in JSON format, here it is (in my initial post)

Comment: Don't you want `Object.keys(JSChild.children).length > 0`?

Comment: Yep, I have got a problem with it too but finally I will use if(typeof(enfant.children) == "object") and it work perfectly. Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Add your solution as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i will use

> if(typeof(enfant.children) == "object")

to check if the parent node has any children.

Thanks to the people who have replied to my post.

Answer (score 1):

`Object` has no property or method named `hasChildNodes`, it is a method of [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)。

Comment: Ok... How can I check if a node has children in my code instead of using hasChildNodes ?